# Space usage when copying

Tags: mysql, mariadb, alter-table, disk-space, copy

## Short version

**Copy table took up more space than I expected or tested**
Why would that be? Could it be the replication / binlog? If so, what then is written to the binlog during this query:

```
INSERT INTO  newtable SELECT *, NULL FROM oldtable;
```

## Details

### Goal:

I'm trying to add a column to a big table. To avoid issues with locking we're doing this instead of an alter table:

- create new table like the first and add column
- copy contents from first to second
- rename both
- delete old table.

This works fairly well for our purposes. It does take some time, but there's no locking.

Now this uses an extra amount of disk space the size of the table (as after step two we temporarily have 2 copies of the data, so this  feels logical), which is reclaimed after renaming and removing.

So far the theory and the test.

### Problem

When performing this on a live environment it used more disk than expected. Not sure how much more, as I had to kill the query to stop the server from running out of space.

The only difference I can think of between test and production, (therefore the possible culprit), is replication.
Can a copy take up extra space, e.g. in the binlog, in a replicated environment?

It probably boils down to: What is written to the binlog during a query like this?

```
INSERT INTO  newtable SELECT *, NULL FROM oldtable;
```

### Context

- System: MariaDB 5.5.43
- binlog format: Mixed
- storage engine: innodb

Comment: If you're wishing to avoid writing to binlog you may try with `set sql_log_bin=0` and then run your insert!

Comment: But then the replication would break, right? Sounds.. sub-optimal

Comment: Not that it will  break replication but won't replicate the change, if that is what you meant! You will have to  repeat the process on slave. 
You can `flush logs` + `purge binary logs` in parallel to this `insert into..select` to constantly freeup the space, which itself is another dirty solution.
Do you have another partition with sufficient space?

Comment: I have fixed the query itself by the way, so that isn't a real issue: I am mostly wondering what queries would fill up the binlog this much, and why, so I can begin to learn when to expect this.

Comment: If yours is row based replication  turn it to statement or mixed.

Comment: As stated in the question, it's already mixed. Changing it to statement doesn't help me much: I want to figure out what exactly happened; changing binlog on a production server is not really going to help me there :)

Comment: Alas I missed that there... if yours is innodb  table it's going to take more space than myisam.  You might like to concert to innodb later?